# MySQL : Getting the sum of multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql

This is very conflict for me let me explain to the best that I could please. This is like a 2 layers to compute. The first layer is I need to get the total A, and total B, and total C, and total D . But, to get the total A is i need to compute some columns, as well as total B, C and D . The second layer is to display and get the sum of the total A ,B, C, D. This is a bunch of tables.

For the first table.

```
 tbl_criteria
 ------------------------
 crit_id | criteria_name
    16   |    sports
    17   |    formal
    18   |    talent
    19   |    nothing
```

The tbl_criteria has a sub criteria

```
 tbl_sub_criteria
 ----------------------
 sub_crit_id | crit_id | sub_crit_name
      22     |   16    |    originality
      23     |   16    |    audience Impact
      24     |   18    |    Appeal
      25     |   18    |    Stage Presence
```

Third table the judges.

```
tbl_judges
 ------------------------
judge_id  |   judge_name
   61     |    first
   62     |    second
   63     |    third
```

Table of contestant lets say 2 contestant

```
tbl_cotestant
-----------------------------------------------
con_id  |  contestant_number | contestant_name |
   1    |         1          |      john       |
   2    |         2          |       sy        |
```

Last table, This is the constructed table

```
tbl_score
--------------------------------------------------
score_id | crit_id |  sub_crit_id |   judge_id | con_id | contestant_number |   score
   1     |    16   |      22      |      61    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   2     |    16   |      22      |      61    |   2    |        2          |     25
   3     |    16   |      22      |      62    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   4     |    16   |      22      |      62    |   2    |        2          |     73
   5     |    16   |      22      |      63    |   1    |        1          |     70  
   6     |    16   |      22      |      63    |   2    |        2          |     80
   7     |    16   |      23      |      61    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   8     |    16   |      23      |      61    |   2    |        2          |     25
   9     |    16   |      23      |      62    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   10    |    16   |      23      |      62    |   2    |        2          |     73
   11    |    18   |      23      |      63    |   1    |        1          |     70   
   12    |    16   |      23      |      63    |   2    |        2          |     80
   13    |    18   |      24      |      61    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   14    |    18   |      24      |      61    |   2    |        2          |     25
   15    |    18   |      24      |      62    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   16    |    18   |      24      |      62    |   2    |        2          |     73
   17    |    18   |      24      |      63    |   1    |        1          |     70  
   18    |    18   |      24      |      63    |   2    |        2          |     80
   19    |    18   |      25      |      61    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   20    |    18   |      25      |      61    |   2    |        2          |     25
   21    |    18   |      25      |      62    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   22    |    18   |      25      |      62    |   2    |        2          |     73
   23    |    18   |      25      |      63    |   1    |        1          |     70  
   24    |    18   |      25      |      63    |   2    |        2          |     80
   25    |    17   |     null     |      61    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   26    |    17   |     null     |      61    |   2    |        2          |     25
   27    |    17   |     null     |      62    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   28    |    17   |     null     |      62    |   2    |        2          |     73
   29    |    17   |     null     |      63    |   1    |        1          |     70  
   30    |    17   |     null     |      63    |   2    |        2          |     80
   31    |    19   |     null     |      61    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   32    |    19   |     null     |      61    |   2    |        2          |     25
   33    |    19   |     null     |      62    |   1    |        1          |     25  
   34    |    19   |     null     |      62    |   2    |        2          |     73
   35    |    19   |     null     |      63    |   1    |        1          |     70  
   36    |    19   |     null     |      63    |   2    |        2          |     80
```

The first layer output are something like this, getting the total A, B, C ,D.

Total are should be display like

```
(criteria 16 has two sub-criterias 22, 23 , that means it will be x2)
con_num | contestant_name | 16_judge_61 | 16_judge_62 | 16_judge_63 | total a
    1   |       john      |       50    |      25     |     140     |   215   
    2   |       sy        |       50    |      146     |     160      |  365
```

Table right above, John has got a total of 215 in Criteria number 16 (crit_id 16). As well as sy has got a total of 365 in criteria number 16.

So, i have 4 criteria in my table 16,17,18,19. This is my problem, that means i need to do query one by one to get each total output and that would be like

```
con_num | contestant_name | 17_judge_61 | 17_judge_62 | 17_judge_63 | total b
    1   |       john      |       25    |      25     |     70      |  120     
    2   |       sy        |       25    |      73     |     80      |  178

 (criteria 18 has a sub criteria 24,25 that means it will x2)
 con_num | contestant_name | 18_judge_61 | 18_judge_62 | 18_judge_63 | total c
    1   |       john      |       50    |      50     |     140      |  240     
    2   |       sy        |       50    |      146    |     160      |  356


 con_num | contestant_name | 19_judge_61 | 19_judge_62 | 19_judge_63 | total d
    1   |       john      |       25    |      25     |     70      |  120     
    2   |       sy        |       25    |      73     |     80      |  178
```

I need to do that in one query, I can do only if one by one getting total A, B C. But i need a one query that execute this kind of output. How can i achieve this output?

The total_a, b , c, d are equivalent to crit_id 16, 17, 18, 19

```
con_num | contestant_name | 16total_a | 17total_b | 18total_c | 19total_d | Grand_total
   1    |       john      |   215     |   120     |   240     |  120      |   695 
   2    |        jy       |   365     |   178     |   356     |  178      |   1077
```

This query, I'm still learning about the logic

```
 SELECT DISTINCT(a.contestant_number) as con_num, a.contestant_name,

//Getting first the sum of total a, Notice criteria 16 has a sub criteria 22, 23
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.sub_crit_id = 22 AND s.judge_id='61' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_61,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.sub_crit_id = 22 AND s.judge_id='62' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_62,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.sub_crit_id = 22 AND s.judge_id='63' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_63,

SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.sub_crit_id = 23 AND s.judge_id='61' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_61,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.sub_crit_id = 23 AND s.judge_id='62' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_62,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.sub_crit_id = 23 AND s.judge_id='63' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_63,

SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='16' AND s.judge_id in (61, 62, 63) THEN s.score END) as 'total a'

//Criteria 17 has no sub criteria                                                    
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='17' AND s.judge_id='61' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_61,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='17' AND s.judge_id='62' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_62,
SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='17' AND s.judge_id='63' THEN s.score END) as 16_judge_63,


SUM(CASE WHEN s.crit_id='17' AND s.judge_id in (61, 62, 63) THEN s.score END) as 'total b'                                                    

//And iterate again for the 2 more criteria
//
FROM tbl_score s
INNER JOIN tbl_contestant a ON s.contestant_number = a.contestant_number
INNER JOIN tbl_judges j ON j.judge_id = s.judge_id
WHERE c.gender = 'male' and c.con_id = s.con_id
GROUP BY s.contestant_number
ORDER By `Grand toal' DESC";
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cfe90/1

Getting the sum of only one total
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9efa5/1

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. It doesn't apply to a single column, it makes the entire `SELECT` list unique.

Comment: There's things missing from your SQL. The rest of the arguments to `CONCAT()`, the `FROM` clause. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Using `GROUP BY s.contestant_number` makes that column distinct, you don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @Barmar, i think its the contestlat_lastname i removed it, its only just the contestant_name now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your query in a subquery, and then add together the columns to get the grand total.

```
SELECT x.*, `total a` + `total b` + `total c` AS `Grand Total`
FROM (put your query here) AS x
```

Comment: What is the next after the AS x

Comment: Nothing after that

Comment: Wow thanks, it works i got the grand total together of all columns but i need to set columns unique because it says duplicate column name is it possible to prevent?

Comment: You have typos in your query. You have `as 16_judge_61,` in the block for criteria 17.

Comment: That should be `as 17_judge_61` so it's not the same as criteria 16.

Comment: You also have `16_judge_61` for both `criteria_sub_id = 22` and `crteria_sub_id = 23`. You need to give different names to them.